# Intent.PutExtra resulting in "null"

Tags: c#, android, android-intent

I have a problem using Intent.PutExtra. For some reason it keeps returning "null" in the intent where I call Intent.GetStringExtra.

This is the call:

```
adresButton.Click += delegate { 
                _cfg.Log ("ID ="+opdrachtid+"postcode ="+postcode);
                var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(Adresoverzicht));
                Intent.PutExtra("ID", opdrachtid);
                Intent.PutExtra("postcode", postcode);
                StartActivityForResult (intent, 0);
            };
```

This is the receiver:

```
[Activity (Label = "Adresoverzicht")]           
    public class Adresoverzicht : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            var ID = Intent.GetStringExtra("ID");
            var postcode = Intent.GetStringExtra("postcode");
            _cfg.Log ("ID ="+ID+"postcode="+postcode);
```

The _cfg.Log in the .click function actually prints me the required data contained within the variables opdrachtid and postcode, but it returns null when I print these variables in the OnCreate function.

Please note that I have only been working with C# for about 2-3 weeks and I also have no background in programming, since I'm following a traineeship right now. This means that I probably know very little terminology and that this may be a rather noobish question. But I can't figure out the issue nonetheless. 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use this code:

```
Intent i=getIntent();
var ID = i.GetStringExtra("ID");
var postcode = Intent.GetStringExtra("postcode");
_cfg.Log ("ID ="+ID+"postcode="+postcode);
```